# Rails: Match all or at least one row using where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On a form user is provided with an option to match all rows or at least one row based on selected users from the multi-select dropdown.

So, in the controller I did this:

```
if params[:method] == 'at_least_one'
  @orders = Order.where(user_id: params[:user_ids])
else
  @orders = orders
end
```

How do I use the where clause in the else part in order to match at least one row?

Comment: what do you mean, "match at least one row"?

Comment: I agree with Sergio; could you give us a screenshot of your form? Is it that you want either 1) To get all orders or 2) get all orders belonging to users selected by your form?